# Any books with Ravana point of view?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

Is there any book ,which is written from Ravana's point of view ?

Like the book containing details regarding why he performed certain actions which are treated bad in Rama's point of view.

Is there book in which all his actions are justified ?

Comment: I don't know such books but Ravana justifies himself in Valmiki  Ramayana. Does that count?

Comment: From his view ravana as first person

Comment: There is A fiction novel called Asura which apparently in Ravan’s perspective

Comment: Maybe the Ravana samhita?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literary work of [Acharya Chatursen Shastri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acharya_Chatursen_Shastri) - titled as **Vayam Rakshamah (वयं रक्षाम:)** - was based on the life of Ravana’s character.In this historical fiction, the author narrated his perspective about the events related to Ravana’s life  -